# Exclude current page from for loop in Jekyll

Tags: for-loop, markdown, jekyll, liquid, static-site

I'm using Jekyll v4.2.0 / Liquid 4.X and would like to create page-based loop which returns related pages based on front matter tags, but that excludes the current page.

My page front matter markdown looks like this:

```
---
layout: test
title: Page about soda and chesse
permalink: /page-about-soda-and-cheese/
tags: soda, chesse
---
```

First I split the tags into an array, loop the pages and then use a if-statement to check if up to three tags matches the tag-string on other pages.

```
{% assign page-tags = page.tags | split: "," %}

<ul>
  {% for page in site.pages %}
    {% if page.tags contains page-tags[0] or page.tags contains page-tags[1] or page.tags contains page-tags[2] %}
        <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This correctly returns the following pages on my site:
**/page-about-soda-and-cheese/**
**/page-about-cheese/**
**/page-about-soda/**

However, I'd like to exclude the current page for the loop.

I have tried solving this with `unless`-tag, but this returns nothing for some reason.

```
<ul>
  {% for page in site.pages %}
    {% if page.tags contains page-tags[0] or page.tags contains page-tags[1] or page.tags contains page-tags[2] %}
      {% unless page.url == page.url %}
        <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
      {% endunless %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Update: Also tried `where_exp` based on this question [Exclude current post from recent posts query in Jekyll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40443429/exclude-current-post-from-recent-posts-query-in-jekyll), but this also don't return anything.

```
<ul>
{% assign pages = site.pages | where_exp:"page","page.url != page.url" %}
  {% for page in pages %}
    {% if page.tags contains page-tags[0] or page.tags contains page-tags[1] or page.tags contains page-tags[2] %}
      <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this myself. Changed `for page` to `for related`.

```
{% assign page-tags = page.tags | split: "," %}

<ul>
  {% for related in site.pages %}
    {% if related.tags contains page-tags[0] or related.tags contains page-tags[1] or related.tags contains page-tags[2] %}
      {% if related.url != page.url %}
      <li><a href="{{ related.url }}">{{ related.title }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```